# Deploy Node JS REST APi Mongo DB on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, mongodb, rest

I'm new to node js. In the last months, i developed a REST API using node js, Express and Mongo DB for my customer.
I would like to deploy the WEB API on Linux, but now my customer asks me to deploy the solution into a Production Environment with Windows Server 2008 / 2012 R2.
Which is the best way to deploy this solution on Windows Server?
There is some best guide to see?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**PM2 on Windows:**

Personally I am using pm2 on my linux machines. Pm2 is a process manager for node apps, which makes deployment and maintainance of your node applications a lot easier. You can also use pm2 on windows, see: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

You need to make sure pm2 start upon restarts / server crashes and therefore you want to setup a service. You could take a look at: https://github.com/jon-hall/pm2-windows-service which may be a help for that purpose.

**Docker:**

If you are just struggling because it's windows and you are still looking for your "common deploy methods" you could still setup a docker container with your favourite environment. However if you don't have experience with it, it is probably a bad idea to test it first in a customer project.